# How to Insert Column in Google Charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

var options = {
    height: 300,
 title: 'Top 5 Debtors By Value',

bars: 'vertical' ,// Required for Material Bar Charts.

```
      legend:  { position: 'bottom' }
```

};
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("ChartNoCallCenterCollections2"));

```
    //Listen for error message and blank out
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'error', function (googleError) {
        google.visualization.errors.removeError(googleError.id);
        document.getElementById("error_msg").innerHTML = "Message removed = '" + googleError.message + "'";
    });

    //var options1 = $.extend({}, optionslight, options);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);   


    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {

            data.insertColumn(3, string, 'color: #42c698' );

     }

  var csv = google.visualization.dataTableToCsv(data);
  alert(csv);

  chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: the style role column needs to directly follow the bar column in order to apply the color -- if you are using `insertColumn(columnIndex` to insert the bar, you need to use `insertColumn(columnIndex + 1` to insert the style (not `addColumn`)...

Comment: thanks,  this is how I understand it, but its not working: 
 for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {

    data.insertColumn(3, string, 'color: #42c698' );

        
    }

Comment: will you share the full code?

Comment: I edited above, I hope you can make sense, the formatting is all over the show